# What is serverAuth and clientAuth?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, config, tls1.2

What are the usage, function, and how to use clientAuth and serverAuth?
Just like `extendedKeyUsage = critical, serverAuth, clientAuth, emailProtection`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extendedKeyUsage` says how the certificate can be used. `clientAuth` means it can be used to authenticate a client, i.e. authentication by client certificate when doing mutual authentication. `serverAuth` means it can be used to authenticate a server, which is the normal case when doing TLS.

For more see [RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.12 Extended Key Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12).

Comment: Is all ssl certificates need the `clientAuth` and `serverAuth` key usage?

Comment: Or only `serverAuth`?

Comment: @CHOOYJ: This is about __extended__ key usage, not key usage (which is a different setting). And what is needed depends on what the certificate should be used for, i.e. server authentication (usually needed on the server side) and/or client authentication (client side, less common).